# How to create animation alert system with toastr and php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi I want to create animation notification system with toastr and PHP MySQL, But I don't understand how can I do that. I already Integrate jQuery Toastr Plugin in my header and footer files I want to create like below picture

[This is example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1JNz.png)

I'm new so I can't understand how I can do that. Please help me.

Below are my html and PHP code. Please tell me How I can call success message, warning message and error message.

````
<?php include_once('inc/header.php');
$database = new Database();

$db = $database->getConnection();

$addmouja = new Mutation($db);

?>
<!-- start page title -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="page-title-box">
            <h4 class="page-title">নতুন মৌজা</h4>
            <div class="page-title-right">
                <ol class="breadcrumb m-0">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.php">ড্যাশবোর্ড</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">নতুন মৌজা</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end page title -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card font-18">
            <div class="card-body">
        <?php
                if(isset($_POST['add_mouja'])){
                    $mouja_n = $_POST['mname'];
                    $mouja_jal = $_POST['mjal'];
                    
                    if($addmouja->addMouja($mouja_n, $mouja_jal)){
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">toastr.success("Have Fun")</script>';
                    }else{
                        echo "<div id='toastr-four'></div>";
                    }
                }
                
                ?>
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="moujaName" class="col-form-label">মৌজার নাম <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mname" autocomplete="off" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="moujaJal" class="col-form-label">জে, এল নং <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mjal" autocomplete="off" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        <button type="submit" name="add_mouja" class="btn btn-success mt-2">Add Mouja</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger mt-2">Reset</button>
                    </p>
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include_once('inc/footer.php');?> ```
````

Comment: Where is your <script src="toastr.js"></script> file located, inspect your page using chrome/firefox and see if there is any errors located in the console section. Then update your question with those errors.